# NSMutableArray and copies

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have 3 `NSMutableArrays`: a,b,c.

```
a= [b copy];
a= [c copy];
```

What happens to the elements that were first copied (from b)?

In my use -case, a is an array I use as DataSource for tableview, while b, an c are arrays that take the place of datasource when needed.
Thanks

Concrete example. In the end I got to use setArray.

```
-(IBAction)selectTab:(id)sender {
    if ([(UIButton*)sender tag] == 1000) {
        if (![self.butonLocuri isSelected]) {

            [tableDataSourceArray setArray:locuriArray];
            [self addPins:self.tableDataSourceArray];
            [self.myTableView reloadData];
        }
    }

    if ([(UIButton*)sender tag] == 2000) {

        if(![self.butonEvenimente isSelected]){

            [tableDataSourceArray setArray:evenimenteArray];
            [self addPins:self.tableDataSourceArray];
            [self.myTableView reloadData];


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code compiled with ARC or without ARC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a= [b copy]; // a is pointing to [b copy] memory location.   
a= [c copy]; // a is pointing to [c copy] memory location.
```

You should use `setArray:` method.

```
[a setArray:b];
[a setArray:c];
```

Comment: if a has 1 element and c has 4 elements, after [a setArray:c], a will have only 1 element. is this correct? it seems to happen in my case.

Comment: setArray: sets the receiving array’s elements to those in another given array.

Comment: [self.tableDataSourceArray setArray:evenimenteArray];[self addPins:self.tableDataSourceArray];

Answer (score 2):

they get replaced by the elements of array c. Plus copy only works if you have implemented NSCopying delegate.